# How can I play Yobi's Basic Spelling Tricks on 64-bit Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, backwards-compatibility, spelling-jungle

I don't know if you guys know the old PV game known as Yobi's Basic Spelling tricks. I think some people just refer to it as Spelling Jungle as well, its from the late 90s. Anyways, does anyone know of a way I could potentially play this again with a Windows 7 64 bit computer? I can only think of downloading an old virtual machine to play it.

Comment: @Matthew Alright, thanks, Im pretty sure I have a couple free copies of xp laying around, I have used VMware for other things before so shouldnt be too much work, was just hoping to avoid VMware, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run 32-bit Windows XP in a VMware virtual machine; there's unfortunately no way to run it directly in 64-bit Windows since it's a 16-bit app.

I use VMware because XP Mode (Microsoft Virtual PC) doesn't support the correct video mode and the game shows up as all black.  I'm not sure if VirtualBox or another solution would work.

You could dual boot with XP or something, of course.